# Probabilistic Classifier in Opencv

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, bayesian

I am looking for a probabilistic classifier in OpenCV, which during prediction, returns the probabilities or membership values of the various classes.
I have looked into SVMs, ANNs and Normal Bayes Classifier(which is probabilistic), but all these classifiers return a discrete class for a given input.

For example if I have classes {A, B, C} and if I give an input {X} I need the membership values of the classes. Like A=0.2, B=0.1, C=0.7. Right now with these existing classifiers I am getting a discrete output(eg- C)

Cheers.

Comment: Random trees in openCV have a function([predict_prob](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/random_trees.html#cvrtrees-predict-prob) that returns a fuzzy output, giving the membership value.

The function works only in binary classification problems. I can use a cascade of RTs to make it work :)

Answer (score 0):

In [this](http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00103955/en/) paper you will find heuristics for multi-class probabilistic outputs for SVM.